# What is this stuff on the Korean SC2 in-game menu?

Tags: starcraft-2

Was watching the Artosis stream and his Korean *StarCraft II* copy that he uses to play over there has some fairly different menus:

[image: Korean SC2 exit menu]

What is the extra stuff at the bottom of the Korean *SC2* in-game menu?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe those are rating symbols.  The first is the age rating, the second indicates violence, and the third indicates use of drugs or alcohol.

Comment: You are correct. Here's the relevant page from the South Korean Game Rating Board's website: http://www.grb.or.kr/english/contentdescriptors.html, though the third symbol actually refers to use of drugs

Comment: Oh, I thought it was some sort of suicide prevention thing

Comment: No - it's actually pretty hard for koreans to get a hold of the game. You need to go to the shop with your citizen card and id yourself before you are allowed to buy it. 
Foreighners need to get a special foreign identity card that acts like that citizen-id in order to buy the game inside Korea..

Comment: There's drugs or alcohol in SC2? Are they referring to stim packs...? The existance of a cantina in the campaign?